# Forçar um elemento DIV no bottom

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, posicionamento, css

Bom dia pessoal.

Preciso alinhar elementos no bottom de uma div mãe.

Se trata de uma telinha de chat que as mensagens são exibidas sempre que existirem novas, no bottom da janela.

Porém, não consigo forçar o posicionamento na parte inferior, assim como por exemplo seria no whatsapp que ao digitar e enviar mensagens, ficam na parte de baixo.

Alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer isso?

**OBS: Não estou usando flex. Apenas posicionamento relativo e absoluto.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colega, fiz um chat mês passado e não me preocupei em deixar as mensagens em bottom, apenas as imprimi das mais antigas para as mais novas uma embaixo da outra e forcei o SCROLL da DIV sempre pra baixo. Isso dará certo na sua necessidade, basta colocar a DIV pai em absolute e as mensagens com width fixo de modo a utilizar mais de 50% do width da DIV pai, assim as mensagens serão impressas uma embaixo da outra.

Olha como ficou:
[image: CHAT - Alisson Pelizaro]

Comment: Obrigado. dica muito boa Alisson.

Answer (score 1):

O container deve ter posicionamento relativo e o elemento a fixar posicionamento absoluto:

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc
}

.elemento {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="elemento"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. É isso mesmo que imaginei. Porém em meu código está falhando por algum motivo que tenho que analisar. Mas é isso mesmo. fico grato.